# Jest snapshot failing test on computer timestamp (AM/PM)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

I have a jest test failing on the date and time, which I think is because the computer settings are different for the user running it. It is a snapshot test, and it's not an accurate failure because we want to show whatever time zone the user has.

```js
-             11:59:42 AM 7/26/2019
+             11:59:42 26/07/2019
```

In my code there’s a getTimeValue which is used to format date to time with point.timestamp.toDate().toLocaleTimeString().

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66749901/14758306) and [this one too](https://www.maxpou.fr/jest-mock-date) but it didn't change the output at all:

```js
let mockDate;

beforeAll(() => {
  mockDate = jest.spyOn(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleTimeString').mockReturnValue('2020-04-15');
});

afterAll(() => {
  mockDate.mockRestore();
});
```

EDIT: I realised there's already a globalsetup.ts file in this project that is handling the timezone, so the problem is actually with the timestamp (AM, PM) and date format.

Comment: Have you considered just using `date-fns` for a configurable and deterministic way to format times?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic the time formatting works the way I want it to, but it's just having the tests run with the same locale and timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

When running jest at node (v12 and below), It doesn't have a full localization. you may want to install [full-icu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/full-icu) .
Then you can just set your test script at package.json with something like

`NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest`

You may read the table describing that its not locale aware at this Node [doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/intl.html#intl_internationalization_support)

Note that at `Node 14` Its now comes with built in ICU. So if your app can run on v14. Go download v14 with nvm and try to run it again. If not go for full-icu to mock the localization support

Comment: I'm running node v15.14.0

Comment: I'd prefer to set this up in globalconfig OR not add an extra library. I don't know why node 15 isn't working

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just needing to mock out the date and time functions.

```
     jest
       .spyOn(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleTimeString')
       .mockImplementation(() => '12:00:00');
     jest
       .spyOn(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleDateString')
       .mockImplementation(() => 'AM 1/01/2021');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mock the `Date`. 
If you use this approach, you can fully customize it to your needs.

```
// jest.config.js
{
  // ...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "./mocks/date.js"
  ]
}
```

```
// mocks/date.js
class MockDate {
...
}

let RealDate;
beforeAll(() => {
  RealDate = global.Date;
  global.Date = MockDate;
});

afterAll(() => {
  global.Date = RealDate;
});
```